# Unexpected results when looking at ASCII codes in C++

Tags: c++, casting, char

The bit of code below is extracting ASCII codes from characters.
When I convert characters in the normal ASCII region I get the value I expect.
When I convert £ and € from the extened region I get a load of 1's padding the INT that I'm storing the character in.

e.g. the output of the below is:

45    (ascii E as expected)
FFFFFF80    (extended ascii € as expected but padded with ones)

It's not causing me an issue but I'm just wondering why this happens.
Here's the code...

```
unsigned int asciichar[3];
    string cTextToEncode = "E€";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cTextToEncode.length(); i++)
    {
        asciichar[i] = (unsigned int)cTextToEncode[i];
        cout << hex << asciichar[i] << "\n";    
    }
```

Can anyone explain why this is?
Thanks

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think € is in the extended ASCII character encoding:  http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: It's probably Windows 1252 or one of the 8 bit ISO encodings.

Comment: ASCII chars are not `unsigned int`s. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @David Heffernan: It's in ISO-8859-15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there's no € in ASCII (extended or otherwise) because the euro didn't exist when ASCII was created. However, several ASCII-friendly 8-bit encodings do support the € character, but the conversion is done by your source code editor (the compiler merely sees a byte which happens to represent € in your editor, but might be something else entirely on, say, a computer in Israel).

Second, `(unsigned int)` casts do not extract the ASCII encoding of a character. They merely convert the value of the underlying numeric `char` type to an unsigned integer. This causes strange things to happen when the converted value is negative - on your compiler, `char` happens to be `signed char` and thus characters with an ASCII value larger than 127 end up being negative `char` values.

You should convert to an `unsigned char` first, and then to an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 7):

depending on the implementation a char can be either signed or unsigned. In your case they appear to be signed, so 0x80 is interpreted as -128 instead of 128, hence when cast to an integer it becomes 0xffffff80.

btw, this has nothing at all to do with ASCII

Comment: Just wondering, but how does 0x80 get interpreted as -128, is that something to do with the most significant bit?

Comment: Yes, the MSB is the sign bit for signed char.

Comment: Yes, as harper already mentioned, it's the way signed integers work in most computers, the MSB is the sign bit, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful when promoting signed values.

When promoting signed char to signed int a first bit (sign bit) is taken into account. The algorithm is roughly look like this:

1) If you have `1X-XX-XX-XX` (char in binary, X - any binary digit) then int will be (starts with 24 ones) `1...1-1X-XX-XX-XX` (binary) -> `0xFFFFFFYY` (hex)

2) if you have `0X-XX-XX-XX` (binary), then you'll have  (starts with 24 zeroes) `0...0-0X-XX-XX-XX` (binary) -> `0x000000YY` (hex).

In your case you want to force rule #2 all the time. In order to do this, you need to tell compiler to ignore first bit (sign bit). For this you need to use unsigned char.